# How to add elements of a std::set to another non-empty set?

Tags: c++

```
  set<int> A, B;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) A.insert(i);
  for (int i = 50; i < 150; i++) B.insert(i);
```

How to add elements of set `B` to the set `A`?
In another words, how to implement `A` = Union(`A`, `B`)?

Comment: What is happening with this question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default sets are unique values only and sorted so inserting the iterator range should work:

```
A.insert(B.begin(), B.end());
```

Comment: Thank you! but I got the wrong question on.I didn't ask what I wanted.Please tell me if I have to post it as another question.

Comment: It's not a good idea to complete change the question after there are answers ;-)

Comment: Ya I m so sorry,I ll edit this question back to my original question and post this as a new question?

Comment: Yup, that would be the way. Also check and see if there are any similar questions on here as usually you can find the answer if someone else has already asked. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 5):

```
A.insert(B.begin(), B.end());      // done
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use another overload of `insert` which takes a pair of iterators as:

```
A.insert(B.begin(), B.end());
```

The above code copies the elements (which do **not** exist in `A`) from `B` to `A` (which means you don't need to handle the duplicates manually).

Have a look at all the overloads of `insert` here:

- [All overloads of std::set::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert)

Comment: The OP was looking for copying elements of `B` into `A`, your solution does it the other way around

Comment: @Nawaz Sorry, I thought you were suggesting to write another version of `insert`. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
template <class InputIterator>
void std::set::insert( InputIterator first, InputIterator last );
```